# Is it possible force playback as realtime in MPV?

Tags: webcam, mpv

I've been using mpv to access my webcam. (`mpv /dev/video0`) However, this introduces a 1-2s delay to stream. This can be avoided by running mpv with option `--force-seekable=yes` and manually seeking to the latest frame in stream. Is there any way to do this automatically? E.g. some kind of `--force-realtime` flag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been using `mpv  --profile=low-latency --untimed` to lower the delay.